# AutoMapper not detecting profiles in external assemblies

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I am using ASP.Net core with latest Automapper. This is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498337/how-can-register-profiles-in-automapper-from-different-assemblies) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58129450/addautomapper-does-not-load-all-assemblies-in-asp-net-core). I think I am doing what needs to be done according to those questions, but still I get below error from Automapper.

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:
ToDoDto -> CreateTodoCommand
Module.Todo.Domain.Dto.ToDoDto -> Module.Todo.Domain.Commands.CreateTodoCommand
at lambda_method19(Closure , ToDoDto , CreateTodoCommand , ResolutionContext )
```

I have an interface which will be implemented by classes that needs to participate in mappings.

```
public interface IMapFrom<T>
{
    void Mapping(Profile profile) => profile.CreateMap(typeof(T), GetType());
}
```

But mapping classes can be in many assemblies since I have a plugin architecture. So, lot of stuff are being loaded dynamically by the host application. My Assembly locating method use below line to load Assembly in a loop until it finishes loading all modules.

```
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(file.FullName); //file.FullName is full path to Dll like E:\Project\Modules\Module.Todo\bin\Module.Todo.dll
```

Once it's done I can see loaded assemblies in watch window

Above loading method gets called in ConfigureServices(). I know this should work because the same assembly collection is passed to MediatR **services.AddMediatR(assemblies)** as well as Automapper **services.AddAutoMapper(assemblies);**

MediatR scans and find all Commands etc. but Automapper fails to locate mappings from other assemblies. However Automapper loads profiles properly from directly linked assemblies via **Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()**

What may be the problem?

Comment: If you explicitly pass the assemblies, everything will work. That rules out AM. Then you have your own code to check.

Comment: Then I am wondering why MediatR works while Automapper doesn't. Same collection I am passing to both.

Comment: Both libraries have SourceLink enabled, so if you think it's worth the trouble, you can always debug and find out.

Answer (score 0):

I got my assemblies to load properly and setup the mappings to work by making my mappings by inheriting Profile class like

```
public class MyProfile:Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<A,B>();
    }
}
```

and not using

```
public interface IMapFrom<T>
{
    void Mapping(Profile profile) => profile.CreateMap(typeof(T), GetType());
}
```