# Automapper error when trying to send POST request

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm new to .NET 6 and im trying to set up a basic API that stores trading cards in a database as practice.

However, when trying to test a POST request I'm getting an automapper error.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
      
      Mapping types:
      CardCreateDto -> Card
      Api.Dtos.CardCreateDto -> Api.Models.Card
         at lambda_method5(Closure , Object , Card , ResolutionContext )
         at Program.<>c.<<<Main>$>b__0_3>d.MoveNext() in /Users/mark/Documents/Web Projects/api/Program.cs:line 53
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.ExecuteTaskResult[T](Task`1 task, HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass46_3.<<HandleRequestBodyAndCompileRequestDelegate>b__2>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

This is my program.cs. The error is on the following line:

```
    var cardModel = mapper.Map<Card>(cardCreateDto);
```

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using AutoMapper;

using Api.Data;
using Api.Dtos;
using Api.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


// Connect to server using connection string from appSettings.Development.json and user-secrets
var sqlConBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

sqlConBuilder.ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLDbConnection");
sqlConBuilder.UserID = builder.Configuration["UserId"];
sqlConBuilder.Password = builder.Configuration["Password"];

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(sqlConBuilder.ConnectionString));
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICardRepo, CardRepo>();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("api/v1/cards", async (ICardRepo repo, IMapper mapper) => {
    var cards = await repo.GetAllCards();
    return Results.Ok(mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CardReadDto>>(cards));
});

app.MapGet("api/v1/cards/{id}", async (ICardRepo repo, IMapper mapper, int id) => {
    var card = await repo.GetCardById(id);
    if (card != null)
        return Results.Ok(mapper.Map<CardReadDto>(card));

    return Results.NotFound();
});

app.MapPost("api/v1/cards", async (ICardRepo repo, IMapper mapper, CardCreateDto cardCreateDto) => {
    var cardModel = mapper.Map<Card>(cardCreateDto);

    await repo.CreateCard(cardModel);
    await repo.SaveChanges();

    var cardReadDto = mapper.Map<CardReadDto>(cardModel);

    return Results.Created($"api/v1/cards/{cardReadDto.Id}", cardReadDto);
});

app.Run();
```

and here is the DTO in question

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Api.Dtos
{
    public class CardCreateDto
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(5)]
        public string? SetNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(5)]
        public string? SetTotal { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? ImgSrc { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? SubTitle { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public string? Suit { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Set { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Rarity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and its corresponding model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Api.Models
{
    public class Card
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(5)]
        public string? SetNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(5)]
        public string? SetTotal { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? ImgSrc { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? SubTitle { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public string? Suit { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Set { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Rarity { get; set; }
}
```

CardProfile.cs

```
using AutoMapper;

using Api.Dtos;
using Api.Models;

namespace Api.Profiles
{
    public class CardProfile : Profile
    {
        public void CardsProfile()
        {
            // Source -> Target
            CreateMap<Card, CardReadDto>();
            CreateMap<CardCreateDto, Card>();
            CreateMap<CardUpdateDto, Card>();
        }
    }
}
```

CardRepo.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using Api.Models;

namespace Api.Data
{
    public class CardRepo : ICardRepo
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;

        public CardRepo(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task CreateCard(Card card)
        {
            if(card == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(card));
            }

            await _context.AddAsync(card);
        }

        public void DeleteCard(Card card)
        {
            if(card == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(card));
            }

            _context.Cards.Remove(card);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Card>> GetAllCards()
        {
            return await _context.Cards.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<Card?> GetCardById(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Cards.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);
        }

        public async Task SaveChanges()
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

ICardRepo.cs

```
using Api.Models;

namespace Api.Data
{
    public interface ICardRepo
    {
        Task SaveChanges();
        Task<Card?> GetCardById(int id); // Get individual resource
        Task<IEnumerable<Card>> GetAllCards(); // Get all resources
        Task CreateCard(Card card);

        void DeleteCard(Card card);
    }
}
```

also here is my api.csiproj file so you can see what versions of things i am using

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>###</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Can you add the `AutoMapper` version you are using to your post? This related SO post may help: [addautomapper-does-not-load-all-assemblies-in-asp-net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58129450/addautomapper-does-not-load-all-assemblies-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Please provide the complete exception message. I believe if you read in detailed, you will know which mapping rule/configuration you are missing. Also please share the mapping configuration/rule.

Comment: The AutoMapper exception in a debugger holds far more information. Please ensure you look at the most inner exception and there take a look at the end of the message. It tells you which mapping is missing or where some went bad.

Comment: @YongShun I think they are using `builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());` as their configuration. Passing in each assembly.

Comment: @RyanWilson, yes the post owner registers the AutoMapper profile, but the problem is does he implement the rules mapping from `CardCreateDto` to `Card`? Second, if he implemented it, does the mapping class implement `Profile`?  So, need more context and a minimal reproducible example from post owner.

Comment: hi guys. thanks for the quick responses. ive added the entire error and my api.csproj so you can see what dependecies/packages im using

Comment: @MarkHughes88 What does your Card model look like?

Comment: @RyanWilson ive added it in

Comment: @RyanWilson well i think the id attribute isnt included because of it being asigned automatically, due to being a key. so its not in the DTO because you don't need to, and can't assign a value to it

Comment: @MarkHughes88 I tested `AutoMapper` using a configuration that explicitly stated a mapping for those two classes with the version you are using and it worked. It has to be something with the way you are configuring the mapper profile using the assemblies, I would refer you again to the first comment I gave and the linked article.

Comment: Still, I don't see you are showing the mapping profile/configuration. You should have a mapping profile class like: `public class CardProfile : Profile {  public CardProfile() { CreateMap<CardCreateDto, Card>(); } }`. Or add the `[AutoMap(typeof(Card), ReverseMap = true)]` on the top of `CardCreateDto` class.

Comment: @YongShun my apologies (im still very new to this). ive added in all the files i think are relevant to this now :)

Comment: Remove `void` from `public void CardsProfile()` to make it as constructor.

Comment: @YongShun ah ok. the problem i get there though is i get an error saying the method must have a return type? that's why i set it to void. whats the work around for that?

Comment: @YongShun so it turns out that that error was because I had named the class CardsProfile and the constructor CardProfile (without the s),

But now i have an error saying that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Failed to read parameter "CardCreateDto cardCreateDto" from the request body as JSON.`

Comment: Yes, I mislook, without `s` so it is same as the class name. How about change you minimal API to this: `app.MapPost("api/v1/cards", async (CardCreateDto cardCreateDto, [FromService] ICardRepo repo, [FromService] IMapper mapper) => { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to put the mapping configuration in the constructor as mentioned in the [Profile Instance docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances).

```cs
public class CardProfile : Profile
{
    public CardProfile()
    {
        // Source -> Target
        CreateMap<Card, CardReadDto>();
        CreateMap<CardCreateDto, Card>();
        CreateMap<CardUpdateDto, Card>();
    }
}
```

2. Move the `cardCreateDto` before the injected service.

[Dependency Injection and Services](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/04/25/introduction-to-asp-net-core-minimal-apis/#dependency-injection-and-services)

> You can get a service injected because ASP.NET Core will resolve types from the `IServiceProvider` after it has exhausted the likelihood that value resolution should occur from route values, query string, HTTP Headers, and the HTTP body.

```cs
app.MapPost("api/v1/cards", async (CardCreateDto cardCreateDto, ICardRepo repo, IMapper mapper) => 
{ 
    ...
});
```